# Android - Remove extra space in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, padding

I have a fragment inside my ViewPager, but I want it to take up all space. Right now there is some space (I set the background to a yellowish colour), which I suspect it could be default paddings added by the viewpager, but I am not sure.

I have tried to set padding on the ViewPager to -10dp, but it only appears to work on left/right, not top/bottom, and it does not work at all on some devices.

[image: I want to remove all yellow space]

My main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#22000000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >
        <TextView
            style="@style/TextViewDark"
            android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_imagecount"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_zoomout"
            android:background="@drawable/zoom_out"
            android:contentDescription="@string/appointment_gallery_zoomout"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/appointment_gallery_delete"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_add"
            android:background="@drawable/camera_add_hl"
            android:contentDescription="@string/appointment_gallery_add"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_add_existing"
            android:background="@drawable/gallery_add_hl"
            android:contentDescription="@string/appointment_gallery_add_existing"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/appointment_gallery_add"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_comment"
            android:background="@drawable/comment_add_hl"
            android:contentDescription="@string/appointment_gallery_comment"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/appointment_gallery_add_existing"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_delete"
            android:background="@drawable/remove_hl"
            android:contentDescription="@string/appointment_gallery_delete"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/appointment_gallery_comment"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_comment_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/appointment_gallery_toolbar"
        >
        <TextView 
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_comment_display"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text=""
            />
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_imageholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_above="@id/appointment_gallery_comment_layout"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</merge>
```

My fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use Hierarchy View to determine where that space is going.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `padding` value from your root `RelativeLayout` (the one after the merge tag)

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/appointment_gallery_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#22000000"
        >
```